# count of elements in a set (not total count)

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have a set of strings in c++.

i am inserting into that set as :

```
m.insert("1-2-35-2");
m.insert("1-2-36-1");
m.insert("1-2-37-2");
m.insert("1-2-38-1");
m.insert("1-2-39-2");
m.insert("2-2-40-1");
m.insert("2-2-41-2");
m.insert("2-2-42-1");
m.insert("1-2-43-2");
m.insert("1-2-44-1");
m.insert("1-2-45-2");
m.insert("1-2-46-1");
m.insert("1-2-47-2");
```

i want to calculate the count of all the strings inside the set which start with **"2-"(count =3)** and also which start with "**1-"(count=10)**.

is there any way to do it.
I tried with `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` but its giving me some errors.

errors are coming for the statement:

```
int i=it_upper-it_lower;
```

I am using solaris SPARC OS.

i just tested this program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  list<int> mylist;
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) mylist.push_back (i*10);

  list<int>::iterator first = mylist.begin();
  list<int>::iterator last = mylist.end();

  cout << "The distance is: " << distance(first,last) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

it gives me compilation error:

```
line 13: Error: Could not find a match for std::distance<std::ForwardIterator, std::Distance>(std::list<int, std::allocator<int>>::iterator, std::list<int, std::allocator<int>>::iterator).
1 Error(s) detected.
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count_if

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your last sentence? (What did you try? What were the errors?)

Comment: lower bound is the right way to go, but what errors did you get?

Comment: i just calculated like this` it_up-it_lb` but giving compilation errors

Comment: @peter in this example works fine http://cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/distance/

Comment: problem might be with my compiler...so i should search for some other way other than using distance

Comment: @2r4w operator- works just fine on random access iterators which set iterators are not.

Comment: @peter Which compiler are you using? That example should compile fine.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry. Wrong answer
**Update:**
count_if is an algorithm to count elements based on function. Try like in this example:

```
bool struct key_part: public std::unary_function< std::string, bool >
{
    std::string _part;
    key_part(const std::string part):_part(part){}
    bool operator()(std::string &s)
    {
      return s.find(_part)!=std::string::npos;
    }
}
std::count_if( m.begin(), m.end(), key_part("1-") );
```

It will count all elements that contains "1-" as part of key

Comment: Is there any other way to do the same..?

Comment: Change the return statement to `return s.find(_part) == 0;` if you want to find strings _starting_ with the given string.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a modern compiler that supports lambdas, you could use those as the predicate to [`count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count):

```
auto if_s_1 = [](const std::string &s) { return s.find("1-") == 0; }
auto if_s_2 = [](const std::string &s) { return s.find("2-") == 0; }

int count1 = std::count_if(m.begin(), m.end(), if_s_1);
int count2 = std::count_if(m.begin(), m.end(), if_s_2);
```